# blender is only rendering a small area of the screen

Tags: rendering

I have tried everything and i cant fix it. it was not like this before and i was able to render the whole image, but now its only rendering a small area of the screen. I cant figure out why its not rendering the whole screen, and i cant find anything online to help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Blender renders what the camera "sees" (whats included in border on the left on your screen)
Move your camera in 3d space and adjust focal length to achieve desired result
I hope I understood you correctly